# How small of a hallway can I take a box of fixed size

Tags: geometry

I have a box with a length of 2210mm and a width of 580mm.  Its thicknes is negligent. I want to take it from a hallway of width 1830mm around a 90 degree corner to the smallest hallway possible (without tilting the box in any direction). The receiving hallway is currently 1500mm and want to see how tight of a space it can fit.

Similar to this problem, but a shrinking hallway not a growing box.
[Moving a rectangular box around a $90^\circ$ corner](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51671/moving-a-rectangular-box-around-a-90-circ-corner)