# Find Greatest length of log that can be floated

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

A Channel of $27$ metres wide is at right angles to channel of $64$ metres wide. Find Greatest length of log that can be floated in system of channels

Is it not the Greatest length of log, the hypotenuse given by $\sqrt{27^2+64^2}$ but the answer is $125$

Comment: I don't get the question. Can't the log be indefinitely long given only the information?

Comment: This has to do with the sofa problem. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922887

Comment: See also here, 3rd problem http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/ladder.htm