# Optimization Problem - a wooden board in a hallway

Tags: calculus, optimization

I want to calculate the maximum measurements that a wooden board can have, to pass through the corner

[image]

The first thing I did was to make a problem easier, when the table does not have width, with similar triangles, calculating the red line (the maximum length that the table can have). I got a function and I minimized it.
[image]
[image]

But I do not know how to do when the wood has an area. I imagine it is a minimization problem with two variables, but I do not know what function to use, help me please

Comment: I think you mean the maximum measurements that a board can have, not must have, to pass through the hallway.  Then you need to define maximum.  Do you mean maximum area?  You found the maximum length.  Do you mean maximum length given the width?  Or what?

Comment: Yes, sorry I dont speak english very well, but I try to find the maximum measurements that a board can have, and I have found the maximum length

Comment: Other approaches to the simple version of the problem are here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583707/intuitive-explanation-for-formula-of-maximum-length-of-a-pipe-moving-around-a-co -- perhaps one can be adapted for the case where the board has width as well as length.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2922887

Answer (score 1):

Let the board have width $W$.  Use the same technique to compute the maximum length $L$ as a function of $W$.  It won't be nearly as clean because the effective length of the board depends on the width.  Now use $A=LW$ and substitute in the expression for one variable in terms of the other.  Now you have $A$ as a function of one variable, so take the derivative, set to zero...